# How to subdivising a pandas DataFrame depending on a condition AND indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, split

I would like to subdivide this pandas DataFrames into N sub-DataFrames according to the state value.

```
        x      y  state
0   71.27  45.10      2
1   69.95  44.53      2
2   70.63  45.19      2
3   69.67  45.16      1
4   70.64  45.59      1
5   67.85  45.48      1
6   70.10  44.60      1
7   70.52  45.37      1
8   68.89  45.97      1
9   70.35  45.15      1
10  71.01  45.72      1
11  70.89  45.45      1
12  69.93  44.25      1
13  70.94  44.87      0
14  70.36  44.61      0
15  71.98  44.60      0
16  70.10  44.72      1
17  68.92  46.73      1
18  69.92  46.06      1
19  70.61  44.63      1
20  70.19  45.19      1
21  67.44  46.27      1
```

I can easily grouped the lines having the same state value:

```
df[df['state'] == 0]
        x      y  state
13  70.94  44.87      0
14  70.36  44.61      0
15  71.98  44.60      0
```

```
df[df['state'] == 1]
        x      y  state
3   69.67  45.16      1
4   70.64  45.59      1
5   67.85  45.48      1
6   70.10  44.60      1
7   70.52  45.37      1
8   68.89  45.97      1
9   70.35  45.15      1
10  71.01  45.72      1
11  70.89  45.45      1
12  69.93  44.25      1
16  70.10  44.72      1
17  68.92  46.73      1
18  69.92  46.06      1
19  70.61  44.63      1
20  70.19  45.19      1
21  67.44  46.27      1
```

```
df[df['state'] == 2]
       x      y  state
0  71.27  45.10      2
1  69.95  44.53      2
2  70.63  45.19      2
```

However, I would like to split again these sub-DataFrames depending on the indexes. For instance, here, I would like 2 distinct sub-DataFrames for `state==1` instead of 1:

```
3   69.67  45.16      1
4   70.64  45.59      1
5   67.85  45.48      1
6   70.10  44.60      1
7   70.52  45.37      1
8   68.89  45.97      1
9   70.35  45.15      1
10  71.01  45.72      1
11  70.89  45.45      1
12  69.93  44.25      1
```

```
16  70.10  44.72      1
17  68.92  46.73      1
18  69.92  46.06      1
19  70.61  44.63      1
20  70.19  45.19      1
21  67.44  46.27      1
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you can identify the blocks whenever there is a difference in `state`. Then you can groupby on the blocks. For example

```
# print blocks to see
blocks = df['state'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
# if `state` is not numeric type
# blocks = df['state'].ne(df['state'].shift()]).cumsum()

[d for _,d in df.groupby(blocks)]
```